# Versioning relationships between nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Lets say there are two nodes A and B,

```
(A)-[r]-(B)
```

r has a property 'weight', that is a measure of dependency of A on B, let's say.

The value of weight frequently changes, and I wish to version the value of weight.
Is it feasible to make a new relationship between the two same nodes, and add a property ['valid': true] on the relationship created last?

I ask this question because I was told that if I need versioning on properties, they should definitely be nodes:

https://twitter.com/ikwattro/status/746997161645187072

But, the weight property between the two nodes A and B naturally belongs to the relationship between them. How do use a node to maintain the weight?

EDIT:

An example:
Let A be a node with label :FRUIT, and B be a node of label :PERSON
Further, let r be a relationship between the two, with a label :LIKING, and, the 'weight' property of r be a measure of how much person B likes fruit A.

The weight property of r keep changing, and it is required to version this property with time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this depends on two things: The frequency of `weight` updates and the queries you will run on the versioned `weights`:

1. If you expect a smallish number of updates and if only keep them for reference, you could use a single relationship and store the old values in a property (e.g. a map or even a string).
2. If you expect a smallish number of updates and if you want to query the data regularly, it would be reasonable to use new relationships for each update.
3. If the `weight` changes frequently and you actually need to access the data (i.e. collect millions of weight values for millions of fruits), I would not store it in neo4j. Use a simple MySQL table with `PersonID, FruitID, weight, timestamp` or some other data store. Store only the latest value in neo4j.

I use both 2. and 3. a lot and even though 3. sounds overkill it's usually simple to implement as long as you only 'outsource' structured data with clear queries.